# How to create programmatically named destinations in a PDF from comments starting with a custom ID

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, pdftk, pymupdf

In many PDF editors, it's not possible to create permanent bookmarks, also called *named destinations*, but it usually is to create comments. It's also faster to just make those. I need a way to can link to them reliabily and as far as I know, you can't open a PDF at a specific comment, but even browsers can open at named destinations.

So I would like to make comments, which starts with an ID (ex. `#24abc: This is it`) and then add them to the outline, reusing this ID (ideally under a title "Comments", for instance). I would need a program capable of searching for the ID pattern, extract the IDs (ex. 24abc) and create named destinations from them. It's important that those can be seen by most PDF editors (I use the command `pdfinfo -dests FILENAME` from *Poppler* for this). I would prefer to use a free software, but I'm open to any, also paid ones.

I checked some tools like *Pymupdf* and *PDFtk*, but I can't find out if it's possible to create *true* bookmarks (named destinations) and how to do it properly.

Comment: @KJ Thank you very much for those precisions. I especially didn't know that comments already are named destinations. Do you know a way to get the namedest of a specific comment? Or even change it? Although seeing the comments in an outline would be best, it would already be very nice to be able to link to them, if I have this information. I use pdfinfo only to see if namedest exists. If I create a "bookmark" with Adobe for instance (which actually is a namedest, contrarily to a bookmark created in Okular, for instance), I see it with pdfinfo. I don't see namedest of any comments though.